# What is the Linear Shading Correction Algorithm accurately?

Tags: image-processing

I want to right a code in C# without using pre-written libraries for removing shadows on the edges of the image and there is a algorithm for this(Linear Shading Algorithm) but I can not understand some part of the algorithm.

According to algoritm:There is an original image and there are two plates as thin and thick(r1,r2).There are ideal gray colors for plate 1 and plate 2.

Formula is:

[image]

Formula for a(i,j) and b(i,j):
[image]

I found this method in the article that was written for X-ray devices but I could  not understand what is the term "plate used for " or what is ideal gray color?Can anybody explain the algorithm for me.If I can understand that terms I am gonna try to write a code for that.

EDIT:I found this algorithm from this book:Computer Vision for X-ray Testing:(Authors:Domingo Merry,Christian Pieringer)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thank you.I am gonna review that text.@José Carlos Santos